# How to disable “External Email” warning in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2013

I get a big "external email" warning box atop the body of every email that originates outside my local domain. This not only clutters my correspondence and creates a micro-aggression against every person I email with, but by blocking the top line of the email it actively reduces my ability to discern legitimate messages from non-legitimate ones prior to opening them.

I assume I can disable this by running a macro, but that's about where my knowledge ends.

Is anyone willing to explain to me what I need to do to prevent this annoying intrusion? Here is the source code for an otherwise blank email that contains the warning message:

> **EXTERNAL EMAIL**
>   : This email originated from outside of organization. Please be mindful of phishing attempts. When in doubt, call the TSC or use the Report Message button in your Outlook ribbon bar.

Comment: This content is added to your email before it's delivered to your mailbox. It can be configured by your organization's network administrator.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator not only can it be, it is them that added this in the first place. OP needs to contact their administrators if they find this annoying, so they can explain why this happens in the first place. Probably company policy.

Answer (score 1):

This is added by your company email administrator and is most likely part of company IT policy which we cannot help you circumvent.

You would probably be in breach of company policy if you did try to mess with this so I would advise against it.

I wouldn't worry about it being interpreted as a "micro-aggression" as it is a common enough company email policy and people are used to it. I see it on a regular basis and never interpret it as such.

All that you can do is try to talk to your administrator about having the message removed or moved to the end of mail so as not to be shown in the preview of messages. 
Any change would have to made for all users in your organisation though, and the message is at the top of the message to ensure it is seen with every mail, so unfortunately the answer they give will probably be that it cannot be changed due to policy.

Answer (score 0):

External Recipients MailTip is turned on by default. You can turn it on using the Set-OrganizationConfig cmdlet.

Set-OrganizationConfig -MailTipsExternalRecipientsTipsEnabled $false

[MailTips in Exchange 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailtips-exchange-2013-help)

If you want to add exception for specific domain to no pop up, check [this.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/533091a6-2e3f-4441-8f2e-fe0d60f068de/mailtips-enabled-for-external-recipients?forum=Exch2016MFSM)